# How do you back up your SQL Azure database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

What is the best way to perform a nightly, automatic backup of a SQL Azure database? I make random backups when I need to before changes using the "create database xxx as copy of yyy" technique but I need something automatic.

I've considered using the Import/Export feature in SQL Azure Labs with a script that runs nightly to export to my laptop

https://www.sqlazurelabs.com/ImportExport.aspx

That sure seems a bit clunky for a service that's supposed to be enterprise ready, though.

Are there better ways to perform SQL Azure backups?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about database backups.

Comment: off topic in what way? It meets both:
"software tools commonly used by programmers" 
and 
"practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development"

Comment: It's an infrastructure question and a chatty recommend me some tools one at that.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used it myself, but might be worth a look at Red Gate's [SQL Azure Backup](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-azure-backup/). It's currently in beta (expires 1st Sept), and is free. TBH, I'm not sure there are currently a lot/any other options at the moment.

Also see the linked article from there to [Grant Fritchey's post](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/scary/archive/2011/04/19/101314.aspx) on the tool.

Comment: Thanks. I remember looking at this a while ago. We're a small operation and we use azure so we don't have to have other infrastructure (i.e a sql server). I think MS has a sync/backup feature in CTP right now, I may look at that again.

Comment: You could use SQL Express installed on a PC. It costs nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Try our [SQLBackupAndFTP](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/) tool to backup Azure databases to a local folder or to a clouds (Dropbox, Box, Google Drive, Amazon S3 or SkyDrive). Some clouds are available only in a paid version, but you can try all features in Trial mode.
Just select SQLBackupAndFTP with Azure to [download](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/#download) it.

Answer (score 2):

The free [SQL Azure Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) now has a command line backup option to pull schema, data (bcp) or both.

Comment: This tool worked perfectly for me - it was also the easiest way to transfer a SQL Server database to Azure.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this great technique that doesnt use any third party tools and is completely Cloud based.

http://geekswithblogs.net/BenBarreth/archive/2013/04/15/how-to-create-a-nightly-backup-of-your-sql-azure.aspx

This post describes how to use the Azure Mobile Services to create a nightly backup.....pretty sneaky!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out: http://www.bluesyntax.net/backup.aspx. I haven't tried it personally but had a brief look at it and it looks promising. Though we also have a product which supports SQL Azure Backup (http://www.cerebrata.com/Products/AzureManagementCmdlets), it is currently only providing backing up your data to your computer with no restore feature.

Answer (score 0):

The [backup tool](http://www.bluesyntax.net/backup.aspx) mentioned by Gaurav provides a command-line utility. The command line utility can be executed on a regular basis using any scheduler, giving you the ability to schedule backups.

Full Disclaimer: I am the author of the tool.